# Keep FTP connection Open until job done

Tags: c#, ftp, keep-alive

I have program which in continousely downloading same file from FTP server, lets say for 3 hours. Everytime the server file gets populated with the new data. So I don't want to connect and disconnect to ftp for these 3 hours. I want to open that connection and keep it alive until the job gets done. Please suggest something.

```
System.Net.FtpWebRequest tmpReq = (System.Net.FtpWebRequest)System.Net.FtpWebRequest.Create("ftp:MYURL");

tmpReq.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("userid", "password");

using (System.Net.WebResponse tmpRes = tmpReq.GetResponse())
{
    using (System.IO.Stream tmpStream = tmpRes.GetResponseStream()) 
    {    
    using (System.IO.TextReader tmpReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(tmpStream))
                {
                    ServerFileContents = tmpReader.ReadToEnd();
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: But the server is not under the control of your code - it's an independent entity that could, for instance, reboot at any time. Since *you're going to have to write code to cope with this, and reconnect gracefully*, why not just write that code now instead?

Answer (score 0):

You can send a `NOOP` command periodically to avoid the remote machine closing your connection.

For this purpose, you need a instance or static class providing the FTP functionality for your program which opens the connection at program start and closes it when your done, executing the (`NOOP`) commands with a timer or another thread.

Comment: @user1335682 how do you access the ftp server? A downloaded library or do you use a custom client? Or .NET WebRequest?

Comment: you should really add this to your question and not as comment as it is nearly unreadable. The `(Ftp)WebRequest` doesn't allow sessions, it isn' designed for it. It is a request->response pattern opening connections just for the request. When you need an open connection the whole time, you should use another FTP library or just go with the current behaviour.

Comment: Ok i just added the code in my quesiton. it should be much better now.